# Adjust STEM detectors gain

Tags: dm-script, hardware-interface

In GMS3 is it possible to write a script that displays the manual gain settings instead of right click on the detector and select « manual gain adjust »?
On the previous versions, the gain adjustment was accessible in the detector floating window

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. Up to my knowledge there is no script access to the detector manual gain adjust in GMS 3.5. There might be low-level script commands to access PMT voltage, but the manual gain dialog does more than that.

Comment: Thank you, and no possibility to display the adjustment window by script ?

Comment: @EricLeroy I'm afraid not. If it is something that is strongly bugging you in your regular workflows, it might be worthwhile submitting a feature-request at Gatan's issue-tracker.